# Can't connect Mariadb from remote client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mariadb

I'm in trouble with connect database server from client.
The id of client is serviceAdmin, and that id have all permission.

- Our Server OS: Ubuntu 16.04LTS
- Our Database: Mariadb 10.1 stable
- Our Server port status.

---

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

And this is our database user list.

```
+--------------+------------------+
| User         | Host             |
+--------------+------------------+
| serviceAdmin | %                |
| root         | 127.0.0.1        |
| root         | ::1              |
| root         | stories2-h8dm8-2 |
+--------------+------------------+
```

Of course the fire wall disabled already

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

But the client (serviceAdmin) can't access database from outside. Strangely that client (serviceAdmin) can access local network example phpmyadmin

==========================

Additional

I scanned my server port, that result is unbelievable

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp   closed ftp
22/tcp   open   ssh
23/tcp   closed telnet
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  closed https
3306/tcp closed mysql
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at that `netstat` output at the beginning of your question:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

That means that your database server is only listening on the `localhost` address.  It is not remotely accessible.  You can change this behavior with the [bind-address](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) option.